# On partitioning n-gons into pieces with reflection symmetry

Tags: discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

Is 3(n-2) a tight lower bound on the least number of reflection symmetric pieces that any general n-gon can be cut into? What if we consider only convex n-gons?

A kite is a reflection symmetric quadrilateral whose four sides can be grouped into two pairs of equal-length sides that are adjacent to each other. Any n-gon, not necessarily convex, can be partitioned into n-2 triangles each of which can be cut into 3 kites which have a common vertex at the incenter of the triangle.

Note: Kites also give *a* lower bound on the least number of cyclic quadrilaterals  an n-gon can be partitioned into.